# Sails-Mongo connects to my database with no credentinals. How can I fix that?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo, robo3t

I recently switched to mongodb database instead of the default disk.

My MongoDB adapter:

```
  ArrowDB: {
      adapter: 'sails-mongo',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      user: '',
      password: '',
      database: 'ArrowDB'
  },
```

At first the adapter has an empty username and password and it created the database "ArrowDB". Now I want to make it more secure by adding username and password But when I add user and pass to the adapter it fails to connect. Obviously because the database has no credentinals.

How can I add credentinals to my Mongodb database? I'm using Robomongo to view my database.

Comment: enable authentication of your mongodb 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/